# C++ Input Filestream cannot read a string from a file

Tags: c++, file, io, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read a string from the file "hello.txt" into a std::string. The string is still empty after the reading.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::fstream in("hello.txt");
    std::string a;
    in >> a;
}
```

Comment: How can you possibly know that `a` is empty, if your program exits right after setting it, before using it for anything?

Comment: @JosephSible OP probably views it in a debugger, but you're right that this is incomplete -- for example we don't know if `hello.txt` contains anything or if it even exists in the location expected by the program.   Most likely `failbit` is set.

Comment: I expect that you have `hello.txt` in the wrong folder or its named incorrectly. Some IDEs like Visual Studio the default location is where the project file is. Other IDEs you need to put the file where the executable is. Also on windows (which hides known extensions by default) you may be confused by the extension hiding and your file could actually be named `hello.txt.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Maybe the file is at the wrong place and therefore can't be opened.

Try this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream in("output.txt");
    std::string a;
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        in >> a;
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        in.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "could not open file!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: With try + catch and what() on the exception it would also be possible to print a more helpful error message.